# SQL Server : Select Local Variable After Some Process

Tags: sql-server, local-variables

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.test2
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @status as int
    DECLARE @error as int
    SET @status = 1
    SET @Error = @@ERROR   
        UPDATE dbo.BView
        SET bview='dar'
        WHERE pt='foo'

    IF @Error > 0
        print 'ERROR'
    else
        SELECT @status as 'status'
END;
```

Why does this query always return the default value of the local variable `@status` regardless of what was assigned to it?

```
status
------
0
```

Server version: MS SQL Server 2014 Express

Comment: I haven't heard of variables having default values. If you are  not initializing the variable then you will get `NULL`!!

Comment: What did you assigned after defaulting the value to 1?

Comment: what is the expected result.

Comment: By default values, i mean if the variable is integer, then result is always 0, if varchar then null. Expected result is to see assigned value, 1.

Comment: Are you sure the value of @status is 0. It should be NULL irrespective of datatype.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: What **version** of SQL Server are you using? The implicit initialization with the `DECLARE` statement wasn't available before SQL Server **2008** ...

Comment: Can't reproduce - outputs `1` as expected .... (on SQL Server 2012 Developer edition)

Comment: It works as expected in BOTH SQL Server 2008 Standard Edition and SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition

Comment: MS SQL Server 2014 Express and tried all suggested solutions, result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

In sql server 2005 : Run this in your sql server.

You cannot assign a default value at declaration.

and post the result in command.

```
DECLARE @status int
SET  @status = 1
SELECT @status as 'status'
```

Comment: What is different in the above answer?

Comment: I think that is what you expect.

Comment: So you are saying `DECLARE @status int=1;` and `DECLARE @status int
SET  @status = 1;` were different!!

Comment: Ofcourse. You are not allowed to assign a value in Declare section.

Comment: Yes this is what i expected, but not with the same accuracy when some other code like update or insert statements exists as in my question.

Comment: Error raise while executing DECLARE @status int=1;  Msg 139, Level 15, State 1, Line 0
Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 3
Must declare the scalar variable "@".

Comment: @Pradeep Could you post your answer.

Comment: Question is tagged with SQL SERVER u wont get this error in SQL SERVER

Comment: I am using sqlserver 2005. It is what I get.

Comment: I tired it am not getting any error. value is assigned!!

Comment: Don't downvote blindly untile you know what is wrong.

Comment: @antioxidant can you please guide tell wht version of sql server you are using

Comment: In question he didn't mention that he getting error!!

Comment: I tested this locally. The original code does work in SQL Server 2012 but not in SQL Server 2005. Veera's code runs in both.

Comment: @Simon, `DECLARE @status int=1` introduced in SQL Server 2008. So, yes in 2005 you can't use it; you will have to use SET keyword. You must clarify which version you are using.

Comment: @Simon Question is no where related to error!! Don't know why this conversation is leading to this level

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions. Although can't find some thing amiss, why not do it the normal way.

**Always Declare a variable first before your update,insert or any action.**

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_test2
    AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @status as int
    SET @status = 1   
        UPDATE dbo.BView
        SET bview='dar'
        WHERE pt='foo'

    SELECT @status as 'status'
    END
```

**Second Always use the keyword `AS` then variable type , the followed by the size. If you dont follow by the variable size, it mostly return 0, note nvarchar types/varchar types mostly. Example**

```
 DECLARE @status as nvarchar
```

Often return 0 when use against a string of length 20 . Where as ,

```
 Declare @status as nvacrhar(20)
```

Works fine.

**There might exist an error in your update/Insert etc processes and i can see u put the declaration and the select process in the same node(i.e begin and end). You can check for an error like.**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_test2
    AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @status as int
    DECLARE @error as int
    SET @status = 1
    SET @Error = @@ERROR
        --Some statement, update or insert, let's say:
        UPDATE dbo.BView
        SET bview='dar'
        WHERE pt='foo'

IF @Error > 0
   print 'ERROR'
else
    SELECT @status as 'status'

END
```

These are suggestions though, I often do this way and it never fails me. FOr better understanding of variable in SQL  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187330.aspx)  and  . Raising Errors in MSSql [here](http://www.codemag.com/Article/0305111) and many more. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for valuable suggestions, I have executed your code result is @status=0 and no error returned :(